# dpkg-genchanges: error: file ../<Software>.debian.tar.xz has size X instead of expected Y

Tags: linux, debian, packaging, dpkg

I am trying to build a debian package, and I find very little info about the above error. 
I issued:

```
 dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc -j3 -nc
```

Inside my build directory, the directory above has the expeted `<software>.debian.tar.xz` file. 
Here is the output:

```
 $ dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc -j3 -nc
dpkg-buildpackage: source package mongodb
dpkg-buildpackage: source version 1:2.6.4-1
dpkg-buildpackage: source distribution UNRELEASED
dpkg-buildpackage: source changed by oz n <ozdeb@yenitiny.loc>
dpkg-buildpackage: host architecture amd64
 dpkg-source --before-build mongodb-src-r2.6.4
 debian/rules build
dh build --parallel
 fakeroot debian/rules binary
dh binary --parallel
 dpkg-genchanges  >../mongodb_2.6.4-1_amd64.changes
dpkg-genchanges: including full source code in upload
dpkg-genchanges: error: file ../mongodb_2.6.4-1.debian.tar.xz has size 43228 instead of expected 43292
dpkg-buildpackage: error: dpkg-genchanges gave error exit status 255
```

Comment: Hi. Did you solve the problem?

Comment: @PSkocik, no I didn't. Other wise I would have posted it here.

Comment: The commands shown are confusing, because `-nc` w/o an explicit build type option implies `-b`, which means the source should be neither built nor included in the upload. Are you sure this was the actual invocation?